# Присвоение значения атрибуту с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('.row_new > #btn_edit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var rtitle = $(this).siblings('h1').text();
    $(this).siblings('h1').html('<form id="f_news"><input type="text" name="" id="f_news_title" value=""></form>');
    $('#f_news_title').attr('value', rtitle);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id" class="row_new">
  <h1>Какой-то заголовок</h1>
  <a id="btn_edit" href="">Редактировать</a>
</div>
```

Никак не могу добиться присвоения атрибуту `value` значения переменной `rtitle`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: Вообще у вас все работает. В вашем примере не работало из-за переноса строки в `.html()`. Но я бы рекомендовал сделать как в примере ниже, пользователя @Visman

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось у меня еще код дополнительный был, который мешал, удалил его и заменил строку как в примере ниже и все заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
$(this).siblings('h1').html('<form id="f_news"><input type="text" name="" id="f_news_title" value=""></form>');
$('#f_news_title').attr('value', rtitle);
```

на

```
$(this).siblings('h1').html('<form id="f_news"><input type="text" name="" id="f_news_title" value="' + rtitle + '"></form>');
```

P.S. А это `name=""` очень странно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!